# Correctly encoding characters in a URL when using HttpClient

Tags: java, httpclient

I have a list of URLs that I need to verify are valid URLs. I've written a program in Java that uses Apache's HttpClient to check the link. I had to implement my own redirect strategy due to the presence of invalid characters (like {} in the redirect URLS) which the default stratgey didn't take care of. It works fine in the majority of the cases except for 2 of them:

1. Escaped Characters in the path or query params, which should not be encoded further. Example:

   ```
   String url = "http://www.example.com/chapter1/%3Fref%3Dsomething%26term%3D?ref=xyz"
   ```

   If I use a URI object, it chokes on the "{" character.

   ```
   URI myUri = new URI(url) ==> This will fail.
   ```

   If I run:

   ```
   URI myUri = new URI(UriUtils.encodeHttpUrl(url))
   ```

   it encodes the %3F to %253F.
   However when I follow the link using Chrome or Fiddler, I do not see %3F getting escaped again. How do I protect from over-encoding the path or query params?
2. The last query param in the URL has a valid URL as well. Eg.

   ```
   String url = "www.example.com/Chapter1/?param1=xyz&param2=http://www.google.com/?abc=1"
   ```

My current encoding strategy splits up the query params and then calls URLEncoder.encode on the query params. This however causes the last param to be encoded as well (which is not the case when I follow it in Fiddler or Chrome).

I've tried a number of things (using UriUtils, special cases for URLs as last param and other hacks) but nothing seems to be ideal. Whats the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I protect from over-encoding the path or query params?

You cannot "protect from over-encoding". You either encode, or you do not. You should always know, for any given string, whether it is encoded or not. You should only encode strings which are not yet encoded, and you should never encode strings which are already encoded.

So is this string encoded or not?

```
%3Fref%3Dsomething%26term%3D{keyword}
```

It seems to me like this is bad input: clearly this is not *encoded* because it contains invalid characters ('{' and '}'). Yet it also seems not to be an unencoded string, because it contains '%xx' sequences. So it's partly-encoded. There is no programmatic "solution" once a string is in this form -- you simply need to avoid getting a string into such a form in the first place. You may be able to construct an algorithm which "fixes" this string, by carefully looking for parts looking like a "%" followed by two hex digits, and leaving them alone. But this will break on subtle cases. Consider an unencoded string "42%23", which is supposed to be a literal representation of the mathematical expression "42 mod 23". When I put this into a URI, I expect it to encode as "42%2523" so it decodes as "42%23", but the above algorithm will break and encode it as "42%23" which will then decode as "42#". So there is no way to fix the above string. Encoding "%3F" to "%253F" is exactly what a URI encoder should be doing.

Note: Having said this, browsers often allow you to get away with typing bad characters into URIs and they automatically encode them. That's not very robust so it shouldn't be used unless you are trying to be very forgiving of user input. In that case, you can do a "best effort" by first *decoding* the URI and then re-encoding it. In this case, if I wanted to type "42%23" I would have to manually type in "42%2523".

As for question 2:

> This however causes the last param to be encoded as well

Similarly, this is exactly what you want. If a URI appears as a parameter inside another URI, it *should* be percent-encoded. Otherwise, how can you tell where one URI finishes and the other continues? I believe the above URI is actually valid (since ':', '/', '&' and '=' are reserved characters, not forbidden, and therefore they are allowed as long as they do not create ambiguity). But it is much safer to have a URI-inside-a-URI escaped.

Comment: @mgiuca-thx for the detailed answer.I don't control the input & am trying to duplicate the behavior of a browser as much as possible. I fixed the sample URL in Q1.The issue with the approach you reco is that when I encode it,it'll go down a redirect path 10 levels deep that is incorrect,and when I try and track it via fiddler or chrome,I see that I've encoded a character or a parameter that the browser hasn't.For Q2,I guess my q should have been what the best approach for encoding query params should be since URLEncode on the query param works fine except when there is a URL in the last param.

Comment: What do you mean "except when there is a URL in the last param"? `URLEncoder.encode("http://www.google.com/?abc=1")` gives `"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F%3Fabc%3D1"`, which is correct. You shouldn't be putting a URL in as a query parameter without first encoding it, or weird behaviour will happen in corner cases.

Comment: had a bug in my overall scheme. This answer helped me step back and analyze it again.

Answer (score 3):

I really don't know, but you can try to first decode it, so the `%3F` will gets back what is was, and then encode it back.

So:

```
String decoded = URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
url = URLEncoder.encode(decoded, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I had a problem where I was supposed to work an encoded String in which %3F had been mistakenly encoded to %253F (i.e. '=' had been encoded to %3F and then encoded again to %253F). "Undoing" the encoding by first decoding a couple of times provided a nice workaround. So the answer here helped.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to encode an unencoded URL string is via URI.toASCIIString().

Of course it is up to you to decide whether the URL is already encoded or not.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using the URLEncoder?

```
    URLEncoder.encode(URLString, "UTF-8")
```

Besides that, your only option is going to encode each URL that is being used as a paramater separately, and then manually building the URL. This is a pretty tricky case.

Comment: URLEncoder isn't any use for encoding URLs, curiously enough. It is for encoding URL *arguments.*

Comment: @EJP There's no such thing as "encoding URLs", only encoding URL arguments. As I said in my answer, once you have a URL, you can't encode it -- it's already either encoded, or you've missed your chance. You need to encode parts of the URL before constructing it. URLEncoder is good for encoding the only thing it is useful to encode.

Comment: @mgiuca You are again mistaken. There most certainly is such a thing as encoding URLs. That's what %20 is for, for example: encoding a space. See RFC 2396, and the Javadoc for java.net.URI.

Comment: @EJP "again"? I assure you I am quite familiar with RFC 3986 (which obsoletes 2396) (I wrote urllib.parse.quote/unquote in Python 3). I'm not disputing that %20 is used to encode octets in URLs. I said there is no such thing as encoding URLs, only URL arguments. RFC never mentions encoding URLs, only encoding *octets*. It says "the conflicting data must be percent-encoded **before the URI is formed**" (emphasis mine). java.net.URI(String) expects an already-encoded URI -- only the multi-argument constructor performs encoding.

Comment: @mgiuca so what is your name for the process of adding %-encoded hex strings to URLs in place of the out of band characters?

Comment: @EJP What is "out of band"? Do you mean non-ASCII characters? To be absolutely technically correct, a string that contains characters outside of the reserved/unreserved set (including non-ASCII characters) is *not* a URI. Having said that, there are situations (mostly in user interfaces) when it is helpful to accept such characters and make a "best effort" to producing a proper URI. I covered that in my answer. But any software that constructs URLs out of strings needs to encode the strings *before* concatenating them into the URL.

Comment: @mgiuca 'out of band' means data that can't be transmitted through the channel. In this case, it means characters that need to be escaped by %-hex encodings. This is what I call 'encoding'. It turns arbitrary strings into valid URIs. I will ask again: what do you call it?

Comment: @EJP I don't give a name to that process, because it's typically meaningless. What I call "encoding" is the process of turning arbitrary strings into valid URI *components*. Say I refer to a script called "abc?123" with parameter name "x<=7" and value "true". I need to encode the script path "abc?123" as "abc%3F123", then encode the parameter name "x<=7" as "x%3C%3D7" and parameter value "true". **THEN** concatenate: "abc%3F123?x%3C%3D7=true". You can't encode an already-concatenated URI because if you started with "abc?123?x<=7=true", there is no way to work out which chars should be escaped.

Comment: @mgiuca Spaces have to be replaced by %20 in URLs prior to the ?. This is an encoding process, and it is not 'typically meaningless'. URI.toASCIIString() does it. h:commandLink in JSF does it, incorrectly until JSF 2.2. I am not referring to URL arguments. I made that clear in my first comment

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding. We're both saying the same thing, but talking about different APIs. I thought you were saying you should concatenate URIs, then encode them (I was saying, you have to encode the components THEN concatenate). But I see you are talking about the Java API URI. This lets you do exactly what I'm saying, but it lets you group together all the components first into an object before exporting as a String (with toASCIIString). Make no mistake that this *is still* encoding the components before concatenating. It doesn't "turn arbitrary strings into valid URIs."